# IntentService android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

I want to make post on network whenever i receive sms the broadcastreciever call IntentService method but it give me following error

```
Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{420eec20 u0 com.example.myapp/.LoginActivity}

11-29 00:03:23.486   W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

11-29 00:03:23.591   W/System.err﹕ at
 android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)

11-29 00:03:23.596   I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

11-29 00:03:23.596   W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)

11-29 00:03:23.601   W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)

11-29 00:03:23.606   W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)

11-29 00:03:23.611   W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)

11-29 00:03:23.616   W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
```

I know that in service we cannot use internet long processes because of mainthread
but intentservice is independant  let me show the code

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this,AndroService.class);

    this.startService(intent);

}
```

**Service Class**

```
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            public class AndroService extends IntentService
            {

                UsrAction upPayload;
                private String smsURL = "exampleurl";
                private HttpClientClass usrpayloader;

                public AndroService() {
                    super("MyApp");
                }

                public AndroService(String name) {
                    super("MyApp");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                    onHandleIntent(intent);
                    return 1;
                }


                public enum RequestMethod
                {
                 GET,POST
                }

                public void smspayload(Context context, String strBody)
                {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    String cookievalue = sharedPreferences.getString("androsession", null);

                    usrpayloader.AddParam("smsbody", strBody);
                    usrpayloader.AddHeader(cookievalue,"value");


                    try {
                        usrpayloader.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String fetchdata = usrpayloader.getResponse();
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(fetchdata);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**BroadcastReceiver class**

```
                import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
                import android.content.Context;
                import android.content.Intent;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
                import android.util.Log;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                public class broadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver
                {
                    private final String TAG = "Hello";
                    private HttpClientClass usrpayloader;
                    private AndroService servusr;

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                    {
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                        String strMessage = "";
                        String strSrc="";
                        String strBody ="";
                        long time = 0;

                        if ( extras != null )
                        {
                            Object[] smsextras = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

                            for ( int i = 0; i < smsextras.length; i++ )
                            {
                                SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsextras[i]);

                                String strMsgBody = smsmsg.getMessageBody().toString();
                                String strMsgSrc = smsmsg.getOriginatingAddress();

                                strSrc = strMsgSrc;
                                strBody = strMsgBody;
                                time = smsmsg.getTimestampMillis();
                                strMessage += "SMS from " + strMsgSrc + " : " + strMsgBody;

                                Log.i(TAG, strMessage);
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(context,strMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            servusr = new AndroService();
                            servusr.smspayload(context,strBody,strSrc,time);

                        }

                    }

                }
```

The question is how can i pass **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** error
and i want to use intentservice methods so is that a good practice to declare object into broadcastreceiver?

Comment: And what did you learn when you Googled for this(very common) error or searched here before posting?

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Google it.

Comment: I googled and saw similar post in sof but i dont get it how to remove this error..

I dont want to use ASYNC i just want to use intentservice and broadcastreceiver 

And my friend told me that the following code is not a good practice
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using an `IntentService` properly.

First, never create an instance of a `Service` yourself via a constructor. You start services via `startService()` or `bindService()`. In the case of an `IntentService`, `startService()` is the typical approach.

Second, `smspayload()` needs to be called by `onHandleIntent()` in order for it to be processed on the background thread supplied by the `IntentService`. To pass the data over to it, package your `strBody` as an extra on the `Intent` you use with `startService()`. `onHandleIntent()` can then call `getStringExtra()` on the `Intent` to retrieve the parameter and pass it to `smspayload()`. You can get rid of the `Context` parameter on `smspayload()` and replace `context` with `this`, as a `Service` is a `Context`.

Comment: can you tell me if this is a good way to call intent service when receive a message ?

   public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //my code
     
     Intent i = new Intent(context,SimpleIntentService.class);
     i.putExtra("string",string);
     context.startService(i);

    }
   }

Comment: @Shayan: Off the cuff, that seems fine.

Comment: actually i am new to android and working hard to understand intents services and context .. thanks for the guide.